# How to read/get job arguments sent using slack slash commands to trigger a gitlab job?

Tags: gitlab-ci, slack, slack-commands, gitlab-pipelines, chatops

I am trying to trigger a release job on master branch using slack slash commands, the job is triggered but i can't seem to get or read the passed argument.
Per the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/slash_commands.html) of gitlab we can pass arguments to run a job but how to read the argument is not specified.
Here's the slack slash command:

```
/gitlab projectX run slack:chatops hello
```

Here's the job in the gitlab-ci.yml

```
slack:chatops:
stage: chatops
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "chat"
script:
  - echo "Hello World, job argument: "$1
```

Anyone already tried using job arguments?

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution after carefully re-reading the [ChatOps docs for Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/chatops/) where there's a `CHAT_INPUT` variable that contains all arguments as a string and the previous job becomes:

```
slack:chatops:
stage: chatops
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "chat"
script:
  - echo "Hello World, job argument: $CHAT_INPUT"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different page in the docs mention some variables that become available. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/chatops/index.html

> ChatOps passes the following CI/CD variables to the job:
>
> - CHAT_INPUT contains any additional arguments.
> - CHAT_CHANNEL is set to the name of channel the action was triggered in.
> - CHAT_USER_ID is set to the chat service’s user ID of the user who triggered the slash command.

Comment: Thank you, i have tested it and edited my answer to add the solution